# I want to get individual element of an arrayList in Java

Tags: java

I am newbie in java and I have a method  that accepts 3 parameters, query the db and  returns result in  an arraylist form (like this `[1, Java, 3, Bangalore, 10]` ). How can i extract individual element so that I can assign each to a var like `int id=1;String name=Java`.

Below is the method that

```
ArrayList searchResult =jSearch.doJobSearch(techName, exp, city);
        Iterator  searchResultIterator = searchResult.iterator();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();         
        String arrayList[] = new String[searchResult.size()];
        if(searchResultIterator.hasNext()){                         
            for(int i =0; i<searchResult.size(); i++){
                //searchResult.get(i)
                out.println(searchResult.get(i));
            }
        }else{
            out.println("No Job found in selected city");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList works in the sense of [index, element].

By using the get method, you're using index as the parameter and it returns the element at that position. So if you're accessing the element by it's index you already have both the id and element, but a different collection interface might suit you better like a map.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 1):

Create POJO (Plain Old Java Object). I am providing example how to array list is used when store Real time Object.

```
package com.appkart.examples;

public class Employee {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Employee(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And Add Employee into Array list and get values

```
package com.appkart.examples;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        Employee arun = new Employee(10, "Arun");
        Employee ankit = new Employee(20, "Ankit");
        Employee jon = new Employee(30, "Jon");
        Employee anil = new Employee(40, "Anil");

        employees.add(arun);
        employees.add(ankit);
        employees.add(jon);
        employees.add(anil);

        for (Employee employee : employees) {
            int id = employee.getId();
            String name = employee.getName();

            System.out.println("id : "+id +" name : "+name);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks android_dev.  for the useful help but i noticed i should have extracted each from the resultset individually and added to an arraylist which do get method returns to the calling arraylist and i have since fixed. I appreciate it